# error: invalid use of void expression, C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a Menu system for a school project, where I have a STL Map containing function pointers in the form of

```
    map<string, YMenu>
```

When I try to call a member function from within YMenu to add a new function pointer to a vector through the map, I get an error saying that it's an "invalid use of void expression." I have attached the relevant code below.

Vector holding arrays:

```
    vector<void (*) () > nextAction;
```

Function to add function pointers:

```
    void YMenu::addNextAction(int index, void (*Action)() )
    {
        nextAction[index] = Action;
    }
```

Syntax used when calling member function which generated the Error:

```
    Menus["0.0"].addNextAction(1, Menus["0.1"].show());
```

Any ideas for possible solutions? I have tried to find on google and searching here but can't seem to find an answer. :/

**SOLVED:** Thanks guys, apparently I made some stupid mistakes back there. I have finally managed to implement the code and get it to compile and run by using std::function and std::bind().

Comment: Which line does the message correspond to?

Comment: Should be called `invalid use of function pointers`

Comment: You want to add the function (pointer) itself, not the result of calling it. Probably `Menus["0.1"].show()` should be `Menus["0.1"].show`, but I sense even bigger problems here. Start by reading a good C++ book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `Menues["0.1"].show()` isn't a function pointer. It is the result of calling `show()` on a specific object. It seems, your `show()` function returns `int`. You won't have much fun trying to shove the function into a `void(*)()` in any shape or form!

What you are probably looking for is `std::function<void()>` which can be used to invoke a nullary function object, i.e., something which can be called without a parameter. The function you want to pass seems to be a member function and as such it actually has a parameter, the implicitly passed `this` pointer. You also want to ignore the return type which `std::function<void()>` will happily to do for you. That is, your `nextAction` vector would be declared as

```
std::vector<std::function<void()> nextAction;
```

However, to actually add the `show` function with the correct object, you need to also construct a suitbale `std::function<void()>` object: since your member function needs an object, you'll need to *bind* the object to the function, e.g.:

```
Menues["0.0"].addNextAction(1, std::bind(&YMenu::show, &Menus["0.1"]));
```

Also note that using `nextAction[index]` is only valid if `index < nextAction.size()` prior to this operation, i.e., `std::vector<T>` doesn't automatically resize to the proper size to accommodate a new index: that has to be explicitly for `std::vector<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

With `Menus["0.1"].show()` you are *calling* the function.

You also can't store pointers to member functions like you try to do, unless you actually have the object instance when you finally call the member function pointer. I suggest you look into [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```
std::vector<std::function<void()> nextAction;
nextAction.push_back(std::bind(&YMenu::show, &Menus["0.1"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using C-style function pointers, use a combination of [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) as follows:

```
std::vector<std::function<void()> > nextAction;

void YMenu::addNextAction(int index, std::function<void()> Action)
{
    nextAction[index] = Action;
}

Menus["0.0"].addNextAction(1, std::bind(&YMenu::show, &Menus["0.1"]));
```